# Logistic-growth equation rate of change

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, related-rates

$\frac{I}{I-50000}=Ce^{kt}$

Where the constants C and k can be deduced from known values. However I am unable to solve for $I$ in a way which leaves a workable function

Comment: You've got $$\frac{I}{I - 50000} = ce^{kt} = \frac{ce^{kt}}{1} \implies \frac{I}{I-50000-I} = \frac{ce^{kt}}{1-ce^{kt}}$$

(Applying dividendo, sorry I've commented componendo earlier)

$$I = 50000\frac{ce^{kt}}{ce^{kt}-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your equation $$\frac{dI}{dt} \propto I(50000-I)$$ is a separable equation.

$$ \frac {dI}{I(50000-I)}=cdt$$

$$ \int \frac {dI}{I(50000-I)}=c\int dt$$

Partial fraction $$\int (\frac {1}{I}+\frac {1}{50000-I})dI=50000ct+k$$

$$\ln \frac {I}{50000-I} = 50000ct+k$$

$$ \frac {I}{50000-I}=Ke^{rt}$$

Cross multiply  and solve for $I$ to get 
$$ I = \frac {50000Ke^{rt}}{1+Ke^{rt}} 
$$

Comment: The OP has got this already and for him $K \equiv -c $ and $r\equiv k$

Comment: So what was the question about?

Comment: Yeah the question was to find $I$ but the questioner has found up to the penultimate step. So, I just commented to say that we don't need to proceed up to that step. Please don't mistake me.

Comment: Yes I started from the first step which was not necessarily part of the question.